# Is this code clean (using policies, resources, form validation)

Tags: laravel

I'm starting a project with a lot of apis. With Laravel 8.

I just made for the moment 1 call for 1 model, and I would like to know if I have well understood the routes, resources, policies, etc... and if my code respects the good practices of Laravel.

My route is :

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {
    Route::apiResource('organizations', OrganizationController::class)->except('index');
});
```

My controller is (for the insert) :

```
public function store(StoreOrganizationRequest $request)
{
    $this->authorize('create', Organization::class);
    $organization = $this->organizationRepository->insertOrganisation($request->all());
    return new OrganizationResource($organization);
}
```

The repository is :

```
public function insertOrganisation(array $data) : Organization
{
    $organization = new Organization();
    $organization->fill($data);
    $organization->save();

    return $organization;
}
```

The resource is (the resource is opened to every one, with some fields more for the superAdmin role):

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'name' => $this->name,
        $this->mergeWhen(Auth::user() && Auth::user()->role_id === 'SUPERADMIN', [
            'contact' => $this->contact,
            'comment' => $this->comment,
            'ads_max' => $this->ads_max
        ])
    ];
}
```

All is working fine. But before to continue for the other APIs, I would like to have your feedback. Is this code fine for you ? What can I add to be more efficient and readable ?

Answer (score 1):

`request()->all()` can be dangerous because when used may cause a security vulnerability.

for example:

```
# database
users:
   - id
  - username
  - password
  - email
  - superuser (bool)


# controller
public function store(Request $request)
{
    User::create($request->all());

    return back()->with('success', 'User created!');
}
```

if am i a hacker-boy and send a payload with `input[name=superuser]=1` magically I will become a superadmin.

bad:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    User::create($request->all());

    return back()->with('success', 'User created!');
}
```

good:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    User::create($request->only('username', 'password', 'email'));

    return back()->with('success', 'User created!');
}
```

Because you are filling the model with the `fill` method it is even more dangerous if you do not have the `$fillable` property correctly defined.

Regarding the repository pattern, I'm not a big fan of it, so I couldn't give you many recommendations on it. I prefer to use [Cruddy design](https://github.com/adamwathan/laracon2017) instead.

Comment: Thanks MrEduar for the warning about $request->all(). I also saw this viedo which explains the problem. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QQS5oEOguRU